# Dual Boot W10 and Ubuntu

Tags: grub

I'm trying to install Ubuntu along side W10 (which I installed as an update to W7). I used to have dual boot and everything was working nicely. If I press F12 when I turn on my computer, I'm presented with two options "Windows Boot Manager (Intel Volume 1)" and "ubuntu (Intel Volume 1)". If I boot into the second option i.e. Ubuntu, I'm presented with Grub 2.02. One that looks like this (not my video): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q9yxg6TG6ts

I can install Ubuntu without any problems by selecting "Device for boot loader installation" as the same partition as I use to install a new instance of Ubuntu. But if I do this, then I can't boot into it because my UEFI BIOS doesn't see the drive that I use to install Ubuntu onto. Let me explain, I ran out of SATA ports on my motherboard so I bought a PCI RAID controller card. This is where I have my Ubuntu RAID 1 partition attached to, but BIOS doesn't see the PCI card or the drives but W10 partition viewer and Ubuntu installer both see this partition during the installation process without any issues.

So the question is, can I somehow point the already installed Grub to the new Ubuntu installation?

Ubuntu installer sees the following partitions:

[image]

Comment: Is Windows UEFI or BIOS boot. Windows only boots from MBR with BIOS and only from gpt with UEFI. Most Windows 7 systems were BIOS/MBR. But Microsoft has required vendors to install in UEFI/gpt mode since Windows 8 released in 2012. Ubuntu should be installed in same boot mode as Windows if you want to dual boot from grub. Otherwise you have to always boot from UEFI one time boot menu. Ubuntu's Ubiquity installer in UEFI mode only wants to install to an ESP -efi system partition on first drive.  And desktop installer often does not install grub if RAID, you have to use server version.

Answer (score 1):

1. Wipe the new disk
2. Shrink the drive with Windows just by 500MB.
3. Install Ubuntu again and create and mount a boot partition (/boot) while using the above 500MB. Do *not* create a EUFI system partition on the drive attached to the PCI-E card.

You're done.